# Get cookie value from Request Header Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, cookies

I have cookie value for latitude and longitude in request header, and want to get that value for laravel controller..

Here's my Cookies in Request Header:

```
Cookie: latitude=-6.1872413; longitude=106.8060503;
```

And here's my Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $latitude = $request->cookie('latitude');
        $longitude = $request->cookie('longitude');

        dd($latitude, $longitude);

    }
```

But when i hit dd, it return `NULL`. How to get data from cookies to my controller?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution,
Because laravel always encrypt cookie, so we need to decrypt specific cookie that we want to allow in `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php`

```
protected $except = [
        'latitude',
        'longitude',
    ];
```